# Slim V2 redirect does not redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, slim

I have a problem with Slim V2 routing instruction. The problem is that I can't redirect to my dashboard page after login!

This is my `index.php` code:

```
<?

    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
        'templates.path' => './template',
        'debug' => true
    ));


    require("config/database.php");
    require_once("vendor/dabble/dabble/src/Dabble/Database.php");
    require_once("vendor/dabble/dabble/src/Dabble/Result.php");




    $db = new Dabble\Database(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    session_start();

    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Rome");

    require 'app/GeCo.php';

    $app->run();

?>
```

And this is `GeCo.php` markup:

```
<?php

    require_once('classes/Login.php');
    use login\Login;


    $app->get('/', function () use ($app) {

        $app->redirect('/dashboard');

    });

    $app->get('/login', function () use ($app) {

        $page = 'login.php';
        $app->render($page);

    });

    $app->get('/dashboard', function () use ($app) {

        $page = 'dashboard.php';
        $app->render($page);

    })->name('dash');;


    $app->post('/login', function () use ($app,$db) {

        try {

            $result=[];
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $login = new Login($db);
            $result = $login->checkLogin($username,$password);

        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log(json_encode(print_r($e->getTrace(), 1)));
        } finally {

            if ($result) {

                $_SESSION['loggedUser'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['password']=md5($password);
                $app->redirect('/dashboard');
            } else {

                header ( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
                echo json_encode('No user found.');
                exit();

            }

        }

    });
```

And finally this is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The problem is that the instruction `$app->redirect('/dashboard');` doesn't work. The browser still remains in login page but in Network inspector I see that the dashboard page is rendered and the route called!

I have also tried many methods with the `$ response` but I did not succeed.

Comment: Not a good idea to store passwords in session. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18991/is-it-safe-to-store-password-in-php-session

Comment: I am not used to V2 but could you try `return $app->redirect('/dashboard');`

Comment: it doesn't work..

Comment: One last thing then is to remove `finally` either run the code after `catch` or in `try` but not in a `finally block`.

Comment: Not even this works .. Maybe I have not explained properly: Slim performs render the page (I realize from the "Network" inspector) but not redirects

Comment: I understand I am just not sure the reason for such behavior. Does the `'/'` path `redirect` work?